# for the tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNN,what's the difference between the state and output

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

as I know 
state = tanh(w * input + u * pre_state + b)
output = state*w_out
but for the tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNN , I just get the unit_num (I think it's the dim of state)
and at the api web page,Most basic RNN: output = new_state = activation(W * input + U * state + B
so can I think in this function
state = output? and the function just has w,u,b,but no w_out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What "vanilla" RNN that you describe does is it computes the new hidden state, and then uses some output projection to compute the output. In tensorflow they separated that "compute new hidden state" and "compute output projection" parts. The `BasicRNN` just outputs the hidden state as its output, another class called `OutputProjectionWrapper` can then apply a projection to it (and multiplying by `w_out` is just applying a projection). To get the behavior you want, you need to do:

```
tf.nn.rnn_cell.OutputProjectionWrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(...), num_output_units)
```

It also allows you to have different number of neurons in your hidden state and in your output projection.