# state output from tf.nn.dynamic_rnn operation

Tags: tensorflow

For this code snippet:

```
rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(config.hidden_size, activation=tf.tanh)
initial_state = rnn_cell.zero_state(config.batch_size, tf.float32)
rnn_out, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn_cell, embed_out, initial_state=initial_state)
```

I was expected the last time index from rnn_out to be equal to state. Or, perhaps the tanh of the state. But this isn't what I am seeing - they don't match. In the context of this RNN recurrence relation, what value does state contain?

h(t) = tanh[b + W*h(t-1) + U*x(t)]

The answer here, implies the last time index of rnn_out and state should be equal (but they are not):

[for the tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNN,what's the difference between the state and output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384791/for-the-tf-nn-rnn-cell-basicrnn-whats-the-difference-between-the-state-and-outp)

The TF documentation isn't clear to me on this point.

Comment: The question linked in the question answers it.